# Get list of checked boxes from a FormPanel (extjs 3.4.x)

Tags: javascript, extjs

this question is probably trivial but being new to the framework I don't know to fix it.

I have this JS code:

```
myFormPanel = function() {
// generate items from pre-defined list
var cbItems = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    var cbItem = {};
    cbItem['boxLabel'] = myList[i];
    cbItems.push(cbItem);
}

myPanel.superclass.constructor.call(this, {
    id: 'my-panel',
    border : false,
    close: 'close',
    autoDestroy : true,
    viewConfig : {
        forceFit : true,
    },
    items: {
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        title: 'Checkbox Group',
        layout: 'form',
        id: "checkbok-group",
        items: [{
            xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
            items: cbItems,
            columns: 3,
            vertical: true,
        },
        new Ext.Button({
            text: 'Send your selected items',
            handler: function() {
                var selectedItems = [];
                // how to get the list of selected items??
                // var items = this.getForm().???();
                // for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                //     el = ???;
                //     selectedItems.push(el);
                // }
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'foobar/',
                    method: 'POST',
                    jsonData: selectedItems,
                    scope: this,
                });
            },
        }),
        ],
    },
});
};

Ext.extend(MyFormPanel, Ext.FormPanel, {});
```

My problem is that I don't know how to access the list of checkbox elements which are defined in the form. Items in `cbItems` don't reflect the current status of the form, since they are used only to initialize the form and never changed again.

I tried sencha official docs:
http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.FormPanel

but looks like I can't find what I need.

Note that I'm using extjs 3.4.1, cannot switch to extjs 4.x at the moment.

Comment: Try Ext.getCmp("checkbok-group").items[0].items

Comment: I get this:
TypeError: Ext.getCmp(...).items[0] is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very extjs specific, as I realized later navigating the DOM of the generated document.

This is the solution I devised, using CSS selectors and the `Ext.query()` method:

```
                var selectedValues = [];
                var items = Ext.query("#checkbox-group .x-form-check-wrap");
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    var item = items[i];
                    var input = Ext.query("input", item)[0];
                    if (input.checked) {
                        var label = Ext.query("label", item)[0];
                        selectedValues.push(label.innerHTML);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should get a reference to the checkbox-group, then you can either use the `checkboxGroup.getValue()` method that returns a list with the checked checkboxes only or use

```
checkboxGroup.eachItem(function(checkbox){
    //do something here with the checkbox
})
```

to iterate through the checkboxes and do whatever you want with them.